# Spring Data QueryDslJpsRepository CrudMethodMetaData is null

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I am experiencing a strange error when running in Websphere Liberty which doesn't occur in unit testing code.
Unit testing is using a `JpaTransactionManager` and WebSphere is using `WebSphereUowTransactionManager`.

The application code is invoking findAll on QueryDslJpaRepository.
When I step the code I can see that it somehow ends up with `metadata = null` after `CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor` and the proxy throws NPE.

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy148.getLockModeType(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.QueryDslJpaRepository.createQuery(QueryDslJpaRepository.java:180)
```

[Larger Stack Trace](https://gist.github.com/corneil/135dc5bd3df6f1362c52f6fdee7ed8dc)

Comment: spring is 4.3.2 and spring-data-jpa is 1.9.4 and query-dsl is 3.6.9

Comment: Which shared library are you refering to?

Comment: The one with the native methods in (since `sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl` is in the backtrace).

Comment: I think that is just part of the Proxy code. It isn't trying to invoke a JNI method at that point.

Comment: Care to provide a minimal reproducible example? Cannot reproduce the issue with WebSphere Liberty 18.0.0.1 and the mentioned library versions. The observed issue is that the proxy routing yields no proxy target hence the NPE.

Comment: Working on a sample.

Comment: Some more investigation led to the following findings:

Comment: During the call to getLockMode() in the QueryDslJpaRepository.createQuery in `QueryDslJpaRepository.createQuery` the CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor will create a `DefaultCrudMethodMetadata` and bind it using the method as key.
When trying to retrieve the value later using `getTarget()` the method retrieved as `currentInvocation` is different during the failing case. In the working case the method is the same the use in `bindResource`

Comment: This link has the relevant fragments and values seen during debugging:

https://gist.github.com/corneil/bd24d77aea7725a4f01183d808ef9100